# Java interface and callback method

Tags: java

Can anyone explain the concept behind this code? I don't know what to search for or where to start? I would like to more about this type of programming.

```
private static interface A {
    void apply(String name, int i, int j);
}
private final A method_A = (name, i, j) -> methodOne(name, i, j);
private final A method_B = (name, i, j) -> methodTwo(name, i, j);
public void methodOne(String name, int i, int j){
    // do something
}
public void methodTwo(String name, int i, int j){
    // do some other thing
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can actually be simplfied to this:

```
private static interface A {
    void apply(String name, int i, int j);
}
private final A method_A = this::methodOne;
private final A method_B = this::methodTwo;
public void methodOne(String name, int i, int j){
    // do something
}
public void methodTwo(String name, int i, int j){
    // do some other thing
}
```

The two variables `method_A` and `method_B` are just regular variables that are of type `A`. The real special thing about this is the value you assign to the variables - `this::methodOne`.

I assume you have some knowledge about classes and interfaces and how their instances work. If not, learn those things first.

`A` has only one method, so you can treat it like a type that "stores" a method. I will explain why.

Prior to Java 8, you would write something like this:

```
private final A method_A = new A() {
    @Override
    public void apply(String name, int i, int j) {
        EnclosingClass.this.methodOne(name, i, j);
    }
};
```

You create an anonymous class that only has the `apply` method. See? Isn't the `method_A` object storing nothing but an implementation of a method?

Since Java 8, you can instead write this *lambda expression*:

```
private final A method_A = this::methodOne;
```

As you can probably guess by now, it's all syntactic sugar. You are basically saying that `method_A` will store `methdOne`. You can then pass `method_A` around and you are actually passing the implementation of a method!

The new stream API takes advantage of this and lets you do things like:

```
someList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The shortcut is interesting!

Comment: @theeminence If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 8, interfaces with one non-default method can be expressed as [lambda-expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Those interfaces are also called functional interfaces.

Your code creates two instances of the interface `A` as such lambda-expressions, which are implemented as adapters to the methods `methodOne` and `methodTwo`.

Basically this is a more compact way of writing

```
...

private final A method_A = new A{
    public void apply(String name, int i, int j){
        methodOne(name, i, j);
    }
};

private final A method_B = new A{
    public void apply(String name, int i, int j){
        methodOne(name, i, j);
    }
};

...
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The link you provided also explains many things in detail.